# problem with linkedIn and twitter (Oauth and SA_OuthTwitterEngine)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-4.2

i am implementing twitter + fb +linkedIn. fb+linkedIn = working fine, but i need also to integrate the twitter with fb and linkedIn. I have sample code of twitter that is working fine independently and separately. I added the libraries (Oauth, crypto, category and json) for linkedIn and Twitter + oauth (MGTwitterEngine, SAOuthTwitterEngine, headers and libraries) for twitter.
But when i try to merge the code of twitter with fb and linkedIn then  program gives bad exception in `SA_OuthTwitterEngine.m` at `- (OAConsumer *) consumer` method on line`_consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey: self.consumerKey secret: self.consumerSecret];`

GDB showing exception:

```
-[OAConsumer initWithKey:secret:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61677b0
2011-09-15 18:58:41.675 thelifedoctor[8086:207] *** Terminating app due to  uncaughtexception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OAConsumer   initWithKey:secret:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61677b0'
```

I guess linkedIn and twitter have same libraries files(Oauth) that causing compiler to confuse.I an not able to configure out wheres the problem? please help me!!!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am facing the exact same issue as yours. Please let me know on this. Thanks

Comment: if u anna integrate the twitter and linkedIn 2gether den u have to use twittpic api raher then Oauth .. Because linkedIn and twitter both r based on Oauth authentication process. SO it is recommended to use twit pic api. u vl get some sample from github of twit pic api